# Flutter Dart: Dynamic Relationship inside Model Class Field

Tags: flutter, dart, model

I've used ***Laravel***, where we can define relationships inside the model itself. So is that possible in **Dart/Flutter**?

I've built this Cart Model where Grand-total should be dynamic.
So whenever I create an instance of this Cart Model, grand total will be auto-calculated once we enter the total & discount. until then the default value 0.

[image]

code from the image above:

```
class Cart {
  Cart({
    this.total = 0,
    this.discount = 0,
    this.grandTotal, // I want this field dynamic: (grandtotal = total - discount)
  });

  int total;
  int discount;
  int? grandTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a getter method to calculate `grandTotal`.

Sample code:

```
int? get grandTotal {
    // TODO: check for null cases here
    return total - discount;
}
```